# Oracle 12c - packages compiled on its own

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Team,

We are facing issues where objects in our database compiled on its own.

Last_DDL time changes on daily basis and due to this we are experiencing  many issues in EBS.

We are on 12.1.0.2 database with 12.2.6 Application.

Appreciate your help.

regards
CHirag

Comment: Maybe something is invalidating them (like something they refer to be dropped and recreated), and they're just being recompiled next time they are accessed. Impossible for us to tell what is happening within your database though.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for iinformation. However, can you please help me how to dig down the issue. As I am totally unaware about it. There is nothing in alert log file.

Comment: See what else in `dba_objects` has `last_ddl` changed or `created` set in the last day or so; or look in `dba_dependences` (or the `all_` or `user_` versions depending on what you have access to) for all the objects that are being recompiled and look for anything common; though bear in mind there could be a chain of invalidations (one object changes and invalidates one package that depends on it; which invalidates another package which depends on the first package; etc.).